# Mutexes and volatile

Tags: c++, mutex, volatile

I am very confused about the relationship between volatile and mutexes in terms of multi-threading.  From what I understand, a mutex is needed to ensure that a piece of data cannot be modified simultaneously be two different threads (i.e., it ensures that the data access is atomic).  The volatile keyword ensures that no optimization is performed upon a variable that could be change outside the normal program flow (i.e., from another thread).

Consider the following code:

```
std::mutex myMutex;
unsigned int myData;

void increment() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(myMutex);
    myData++;
}

unsigned int get() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(myMutex);
    unsigned int tmp = myData;
    return tmp;
}
```

(I am aware that the above example could be simplified using `std::atomic` but assume `myData` could be something more complex)

Based upon my understanding, even though `myData` is protected via the mutex, shouldn't it also be marked as volatile because it can/will be modified from different threads?

Comment: There's no relationship of `volatile` and `std::mutex`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can you elaborate?

Comment: A mutex lock prevents that a section of code will be executed by multiple threads simultaneously, so making the variable that is modified in such a section atomic is redundant (also `volatile` is not guaranteed by the standard to do anything in regards to multithreading, *some* compilers do that though)

Comment: Can you elaborate your concern? `volatile` just prevents the compiler to optimize away values, which could be changed due to hardware or OS behavior. Nothing to do with thread safety or such.

Comment: _"...This makes volatile objects suitable for communication with a signal handler, __but not with another thread__ of execution, see std::memory_order)...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My concern is that switching of threads (which usually occurs due to an ISR) is, in my mind, the same as data being modified by some uncontrollable event.  For example, if one of my functions above was an interrupt service routine, then wouldn't myData have to be marked volatile?  Is there truly a different between a "different thread" and an "interrupt service routine?"

Comment: @PatrickWright `volatile` is completely unrelated to multithreading. If the platform requires special instructions to synchronize a variable across threads, the compiler will insert those whenever synchronization occurs, such as locking a mutex.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is the idea that, if something is protected by a mutex/critical section, it is impossible for that piece of data to change while within the critical section, thus volatile is not needed/redundant?  For example, myData cannot change while get() has the mutex.

Comment: a use for `volatile` is to prevent the compiler from optimizing away unnecessary reads or writes, not to protect varibles to change their value unexpectedly. If that was the case you would want to declare anything as `volatile`, no?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I think I am beginning to understand.  A register mapped to a variable should be volatile because it is modified by hardware and needs to be read from hardware each time it is accessed.  However, a variable modified by another thread (or ISR) (i.e., a different program flow) can just be protected by a mutex which prevents it from being change unexpectedly.  Am I correct?

Comment: @PatrickWright `volatile` does not ensure that all cores, caches, main memory, have the same value ie data is __not__ synchronised at the hardware level.  A volatile read may read old data (from a cache), a volatile write may not be seen by other threads and multi-byte objects will be subject to tearing as part written data may be seen by reads on other threads.

Comment: I think, you should not mix ISRs and threads. They are handled differently, and for ISRs, you need a different approach. For example, using mutexes in ISRs is a bad idea, since it will likely lead to a deadlock.